# I have some problem about show last saved CoreData data in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I save data from `MovieDetailViewController` in coreData. I try to access coreData data from another controller. When I save the data to coreData and switch to another controller where I output the result in tableView, it doesn't show me the newly saved names there. When I delete the background and reopen it then it shows me the last saved data.

I need something similar to the tableView method `tableView.reloadData()`.

```
class MovieDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var coreDataMovieName: [NSManagedObject] = []
    var movie: Movie!
    var detailsImageView: UIImage!
    var movieName = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = movie.title

        //Detalebshi Photos gamochena
        if let posterPath = movie.posterPath {
            TMDBClient.downloadPosterImage(path: posterPath) { (data, error) in
                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self.imageView.image = image
                self.detailsImageView = image
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Favorite")
        do {
            coreDataMovieName = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }


    func save(name: String) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Favorite", in: managedContext)!
        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
        person.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "movieName")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            coreDataMovieName.append(person)
            print("saved \(person)")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func coreDataFavoritesBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        save(name: movieName)
    }
}
```

A controller where I try to access Core Data:

```
class CoreDataFavoritesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    var movie: [NSManagedObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "The List"
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Favorite")

        do {
            movie = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension CoreDataFavoritesViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return movie.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let person = movie[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = person.value(forKeyPath: "movieName") as? String
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending Data after context save

```
 coreDataMovieName.append(person)
```

do it before

```
try managedContext.save()
```

Comment: I did it too, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: when you fectch data in CoreDataFavoritesViewController .... does that record appear ?

Comment: new record appears CoreDataFavoritesViewController,  When I delete my app in the background and reopen it then it shows me the last saved data.

Comment: If I go to **CoreDataFavoritesViewController** after saving, the last saved data will not appear until delete it from the background and log in again.